# ¿Cómo editar una tabla con llaves primarias y foráneas de MySQL con C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

A continuación dejo el código de la modificación dentro del botón de edición en el formulario:

```
string actualizar = "IDUsuario = '" + txtIDUsuario.Text + "', Password = MD5('" + TxtContraseña.Text + "'), MetodoEncriptado = 'MD5', TipoUsuario ='" + TipoUsuario + "', Nombres = '" + txtNombresUsuarios.Text + "', Apellidos= '" + txtApellidosUsuario.Text + "', FechaNacimiento = '" + fechaComoQuiero + "', Telefono = '" + txtNumeroUsuario.Text + "', CorreoElectronico = '" + txtCorreoUsuario.Text + "', RedSocial = '" + rtxtRedSocialUsuario.Text + "', Direccion = '" + rtxtDireccionUsuario.Text + "';";
if (con.Actualizar("Usuarios", actualizar, " IDUsuario = " + txtIDUsuario.Text + ";")) {
    MessageBox.Show("Datos Editados");
} else {
    MessageBox.Show("Datos fallidos");
}
```

Seguido del método de edición en la clase de conexión:

```
public bool Actualizar(string tabla, string campos, string condicion)
{
    string actualizar = "update " + tabla + " set " + campos + " where" + condicion;
    comando = new MySqlCommand(actualizar, Con);
    int i = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (i > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Supongo que la lógica está bien, pero cada vez que ejecuto el procedimiento, visual studio encuentra una excepción sql que recita:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`hssp`.`bloqueados`, CONSTRAINT `bloqueados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`IDUsuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`IDUsuario`))

Según entiendo no puedo alterar nada que tenga llaves conectadas. Pero entonces, ¿cómo puedo modificar datos de las tablas?

Por último detallo estructura de mi tabla:

```
create table Usuarios (
    IDUsuario varchar(16) not null primary key, /*Llave primaria*/ /*En               todos los caso alternos, es llave foránea. Deberá crearse en las demás tablas  como un campo común*/
    Password varchar(40) not null,
    MetodoEncriptado varchar(5) not null,
    TipoUsuario int(1) not null,
    Nombres varchar(20) not null,
    Apellidos varchar(20) not null,
    FechaNacimiento date not null,
    Telefono numeric (12) not null,
    CorreoElectronico varchar(60) not null,
    RedSocial varchar(100) not null,
    Direccion varchar(60) not null
)
```

Comment: Nunca se debería modificar la clave primaria. Si realmente tienes necesidad de modificarla, probablemente significa que esa columna no debía haber sido la clave primaria en primer lugar.

Comment: Perfecto y ya implementado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si te ha sido útil se agradecería que marcaras la pregunta como respondida y si no te sirvieron las respuestas y la solución la has encontrado tú también te puedes responder a ti mismo para saber cómo lo solucionaste. Así el resto se puede beneficiar de tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

En la consulta que haces intentas actualizar la clave primaria. Suponiendo que la clave sólo la vas a usar para actualizar el resto de los datos **quita `IDUsuario` de los campos y ponlo sólo en la condición**.
Por otra parte sería mejor que construyeras tu consulta de una manera mejor que concatenando los campos para evitar lo que se llama **[Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)**

Comment: No basta con validar mis controles para evitar algunos digitos que componen la inyección?

Comment: @GabrielHernández La verdad es que no es tan simple. Podrías implementarlo y perder un montón de tiempo, pero para eso usa lo que ya está hecho, preparado, probado y mantenido por una comunidad o empresa que cobra por ello y que cuando se descubran nuevos ataques se parchee ¿no?

Comment: Es verdad. Por cuestiones de tiempo, no voy a hacer más que validar. A parte, es con fines académicos y los requisitos de seguridad son nulos, a penas es Programación II y en lo que se están centrando es en la fluidez y conectibilidad.